# Inspecting a function annotated by string

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have some type hints like below:

```
class ABC: 
    def carl(self) -> 'DEF':
         pass
class DEF: 
    pass
```

I should mention type hint in string, because `class DEF` defined below `class ABC`. Actuality this is the way we handle type hinting before definition.

But I need to get type hint of return value of `carl` method in another place, and I use `inspect.signature()` method by its `return_annotation` parameter. I just get `"DEF"` in string.

I want to have `<class DEF>` or something usefull instead.

Comment: cant you just make ```DEF``` instead of ```"DEF"```

Comment: It raises `NameError` when you not defined the corresponding object before.